# Three20 library support to apple

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, three20

Is three20 library supported by apple? Or apple rejects the app which includes this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple doesn't reject apps written using Three20. Here is list of few apps on App Store using three20 in their project : http://three20.info/gallery

Comment: Thanks. Is there any tool to generate rich text editor using three20 library. I have to change the font of selected text in uitextview.

Comment: Look at this http://www.honcheng.com/2011/05/RTLabel---rich-formating-display-for-iOS-using-HTML-like-markup

Comment: sorry but, this example is for label. I want to edit the formatted text and apply font styles to selected text in textview which is multiline.

Answer (score 0):

Apps Using the Three20 are also accepted. SInce last 2 years we are developing iOS applications using Three20

You can see many examples on Three20 official website.